# T-SQL stored procedure, use variable as table reference in query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure which is working well;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[currentCoForHiLo] 
    @CoKeyCode Char(50)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE ##WrkedOnCo(cKeyCode Char(50), DateInt Int, HighValu Int, LowValu Int)

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_CI ON ##WrkedOnCo(DateInt)

    INSERT INTO ##WrkedOnCo 
        SELECT KeyCode, DateAsInt, HighValu, LowValu 
        FROM EODValuesAU 
        WHERE KeyCode = @CoKeyCode;
END
```

The procedure was getting data from one table `EODValuesAU`.

I now have multiple tables `EODValuesAU`, `EODValuesUS`, `EODValuesUK`.

I have tried altering the code to the following but the query now has errors. I want to use a variable for the table in the query. Is there any way I can do this. See altered code below;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[currentCoForHiLo] 
    @CoKeyCode Char(50), @CounrtyCode Char(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE ##WrkedOnCo(cKeyCode Char(50), DateInt Int, HighValu Int, LowValu Int)

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_CI ON ##WrkedOnCo(DateInt)

    INSERT INTO ##WrkedOnCo 
        SELECT KeyCode, DateAsInt, HighValu, LowValu 
        FROM 'EODValues' + @CountryCode 
        WHERE KeyCode = @CoKeyCode;
END
```

Comment: Why don't you have a single `EODValues` table with a country *column* that can contain `UK`, `US`, `AU`, and therefore a straightforward, normal, query? At the moment, you've made the mistake of embedding "queryable" data in the *metadata* instead, by placing it in the table name.

Comment: you cannot use expressions or variables as Table Name. Its best to create dynamic sql if you want to use dynamic names.

Comment: Why are you creating and inserting into a global temp table? This will mean that concurrent calls to the stored proc can fail and you don't need any sort of temp table in the code shown.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is your friend here.

Instead of the INSERT, try something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(400);
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ##WrkedOnCo SELECT KeyCode, DateAsInt, HighValu, LowValu FROM EODValues'+@CountryCode+' WHERE KeyCode = @CoKeyCode;';
PRINT @sql;  --check its what you want first
--EXEC (@sql);
```

Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment would be the best, dynamic SQL can get messy pretty quickly

Answer (score 0):

```
-- you Have to Use Dynamic Query to desire Output


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[currentCoForHiLo] 
    @CoKeyCode NVARCHAR(50),@CounrtyCode NVARCHAR (10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE ##WrkedOnCo(cKeyCode NVARCHAR(50), DateInt Int, HighValu Int, LowValu Int)

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_CI ON ##WrkedOnCo(DateInt)

    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(4000)
    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ##WrkedOnCo 
                SELECT KeyCode, DateAsInt, HighValu, LowValu FROM EODValues'+@CounrtyCode+' WHERE KeyCode = '''+@CoKeyCode+'''';
    PRINT @sql;  
    EXEC (@sql);
END
```